# Correct Semantic tag for copyright info - html5

Tags: html, semantic-markup

What would be the best and most semantic tag/method for including a copyright notice in the footer of a web site?

Answer (score 102):

Put it inside your `<footer>` by all means, but the most fitting element is [the small element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element).

The HTML5 spec for this says:

> Small print typically features
>   disclaimers, caveats, legal
>   restrictions, or copyrights. Small
>   print is also sometimes used for
>   attribution, or for satisfying
>   licensing requirements.

Answer (score 91):

it is better to include it in a `<small>` tag 
The HTML `<small>` tag is used for specifying small print.

Small print (also referred to as "fine print" or "mouseprint") usually refers to the part of a document that contains disclaimers, caveats, or legal restrictions, such as copyrights.
And this tag is supported in all major browsers.

```
<footer>
 <small>&copy; Copyright 2058, Example Corporation</small>
</footer>
```

Comment: How about further embedding the "Example Corporation" in an address tag? Or is that displayed as a block? And this is not a complete address?

Comment: @masterxilo address will be displayed as block and small as block.
<footer> <small>© Copyright 2058, 
<address>
    <a href="mailto:info@example.com">Example Corporation</a>.
    <div>Visit us at:
Example.com
Box 564, Disneyland
        USA  </div>

</address>
</small>
</footer>

Try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/PqJCL/

Answer (score 11):

The [`<footer>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/footer.html) tag seems like a good candidate:

```
<footer>&copy; 2011 Some copyright message</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks Darin.  Thats what I am doing at the moment although I had wondered if there was someway to seperate the copyright info from the other footer content in a semantic way

Comment: @David, no there isn't. The `<footer>` could be used for this purpose.

Comment: Just to expand: 
"The footer element represents a footer for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element. A footer typically contains information about its section such as who wrote it, links to related documents, copyright data, and the like."http://developers.whatwg.org/sections.html#the-footer-element

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Yes. There is. We should use `small` tag for that.

Comment: `<footer><small>&copy; 2011 Some copyright message</small></footer>`

Answer (score 7):

In a link, if you put rel=license it:
Indicates that the main content of the current document is covered by the copyright license described by the referenced document.
Source: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/link

So, for example, `<a rel="license" href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/">Copyrighted but you can use what's here as long as you credit me</a>` gives a human something to read and lets computers know that the rest of the page is licensed under the CC BY 4.0 license.