# Suitable Tag for copyright content inside footer

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I was attempting an assessment for a job.

The task was to convert `div` tags to proper HTML5 semantics tags. I was not allowed to modify/remove anything else.

The code for footer was like this:

```html
<div class="footer">
    <div class="copyright-content">
        <div class="copyright"> copyright 20xx -xx </div>
        <p> by xyz company </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

There were three separate checks for each div. Passing the first one was easy.

```html
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="copyright-content">
        <div class="copyright"> copyright 20xx -xx </div>
        <p> by xyz company </p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

But I could not figure out the correct tag for the next div (with the class `copyright-content`).
I tried `section`, `article`, `nav`, `blockquote` and few more tags but none of those worked.

I cannot reattempt the test anymore but does anyone know what could have been the possible correct tag?

Comment: Maybe `<small>`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876021/correct-semantic-tag-for-copyright-info-html5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct Semantic tag for copyright info - html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876021/correct-semantic-tag-for-copyright-info-html5)

Comment: Which tag should be used is subject to opinion and a horrible test question. `<small>` would be wrong as a container for a `<div>` and a `<p>` and both of those are wrong for the content shown. That layout is also horrible.

Comment: I had tried `small` but it was outright wrong as `small` cannot contain those two inner elements and the question explicitly mentioned not to change anything other than `div` tags. I did not try changing the `p` tag during assessment but may be this is what they wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what they were looking for:

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <small class="copyright-content">
    <span class="copyright"> copyright 20xx -xx </span>
    <span> by xyz company </span>
  </small>
</footer>
```

The [`<small>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/small) is for—

> ...side-comments and small print, like copyright and legal text...

It's also important to know (as Rob points out) that a `<small>` element can't contain a `<div>` or a `<p>` element. `<small>` elements can only contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content), so those other two elements need to change to something that *is* phrasing content.

A [`<span>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) is probably most appropriate for both. Neither the copyright nor the company need additional semantics beyond those imparted by the `<small>`. A `<span>` is phrasing content and semantic-less, so it's a perfect fit.

The [MDN Web Docs: HTML Element Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) guide is an excellent resource for learning about all the available tags, what semantics they carry, and how they can (and can't) be used.

Comment: I had tried `small` but it was outright wrong as `small` cannot contain those two inner elements and the question explicitly mentioned not to change anything other than `div` tags. I did not try changing the `p` tag during assessment but may be this is what they wanted.

Comment: Sounds like the instructions may have been inaccurate, misleading, or misinterpreted. You're right that smalls can't contain divs, but the small/span combo is definitely most appropriate here. May be worth reaching out to them about it?